# How to use Hindi Language in text view on Eclipse

Tags: android, textview

I want to Hindi text on Textview but it showing nothing. what is the codes to install the hindi fonts on Eclipse. I couldn't find proper codes to implement on it. So please give me some idea to use Hindi text on my project.

Comment: I quickly Googled: **using non english language in android eclipse** and I found http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: You might not want to include "Sir" in questions. I'm sure you mean no insult, but female engineers find it off-putting.